# Express Redis Session Crash with response status zero

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, express, redis

I'm currently having some problem with using Redis as a session storage for my NodeJS-Express application. At some point, while my application is awaiting for mongoDB promise to respond to a query, the Redis Session suddenly crashes the whole application.

### Stack trace:

```logtalk
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/my_project_path/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/my_project_path/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/my_project_path/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (/my_project_path/node_modules/compression/index.js:102:14)
    at writeend (/my_project_path/node_modules/express-session/index.js:261:22)
    at Command.ontouch (/my_project_path/node_modules/express-session/index.js:348:11)
    at Command.callback (/my_project_path/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:248:10)
    at normal_reply (/my_project_path/node_modules/redis/index.js:721:21)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/my_project_path/node_modules/redis/index.js:819:9)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/my_project_path/node_modules/redis/index.js:192:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/my_project_path/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:574:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/my_project_path/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

I have tried many ways to intercept the error, but to no avail: it occurs out of any hook or *console.log* I try. I tried searching google and stackOverflow but all I can find are some people that were mistakingly sending zero-statuses in their own codes, not any error with express<->redis sessions.

### Express config code

Below, the code I'm using to connect Express with Redis:

```js
const config = {...config data here...}
const session = require('express-session'); // version 1.15.3
const redis = require('redis'); // version 2.7.1, 
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session); // version 3.3.0

const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: config.redisCache.host,
  port: config.redisCache.port,
  auth_pass: config.redisCache.token
});
redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
  // This is never called
  console.error("Redis Error " + JSON.stringify(err,null,2));
});

const sess = {
    resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: true,// don't create session until something stored,
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    store: new RedisStore({client:redisClient}),
    logErrors: function(_err) {
      // This is never called either
      console.error('Session error:' + JSON.stringify(_err,null,2)) 
    }
  };
app.use(session(sess));
```

### Requests' data

Below, the two requests I'm sending. One, from my client AngularJS app, crashes the server. The other receives a response just fine, to complete my confusion.

```js
// AngularJS request - crashes server with above stacktrace
{
  "host": "localhost:8082",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "54",
  "origin": "http://localhost:8082",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "apptoken": "my_project_app_token",
  "referer": "http://localhost:8082/",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6",
  "cookie": "connect.sid=s%3A14363a00-6285-11e7-8c76-9366761bb151.1Yg2b6gsLR8uJ7OCwLshZDacMbNC3XASI4%2BxVlRZ%2BXg"
}

// PostMan request, works just fine! (??)
{
  "host": "localhost:8082",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "57",
  "postman-token": "86a514cd-7c19-85ee-d831-3b032849d430",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "origin": "chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
  "apptoken": "my_project_app_token",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6",
  "cookie": "connect.sid=s%3AdUYMmy7KkcUF-tS9eHHbOTgNW4YrKx92.elK9FAP6kuZ3aazh8Z5X8m1lSZX%2BO4sIcex0LLD7JBQ"
}

// For completeness' sake, here is the POST request body
{"phone":"9999999999999","email":"xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx.xx"}
```

Any ideas that point me in a way to fix this crash or investigate further will be very welcome!

Comment: Does it happen when you don't set `sess.store` (so `express-session` would fall back to using the built-in `MemoryStore`)? Also, can you show the code that _"is awaiting for mongoDB promise to respond to a query"_?

Comment: Nice ideas, @robertklep! As for the code that is awayting for MongoDB, it could be any code: I tried inserting an arbitrary `setTimeOut` and not run any code at all: it just crashed anyway.
In the end it was some dependency bug... I'll post an answer to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I decided to update all my `npm` packages in the most brute way I could:

- Deleted all my dependencies with `rm -rf node_modules`
- Updated my `package.json` with the exact version of all my dependencies (no "carets" or "greater than")
- Then `npm install` on the clean project.

The app's session started working again!
Hope this Q&A helps someone else passing by this weird bug.